# Tail recursion without tail call optimization

Tags: recursion, optimization, tail-recursion

Let say we had two versions of a recursive function, with one of them being tail-recursive. Is there any benefit in using the function tail recursive if the language being used does not have tail-call optimization? From my understanding, without the optimization, each version of a function (tail and non-tail) would use the same number of stack frames (in most cases).

I know that in some cases, like the Fibonacci function for example, using a tail call can be more efficient even without tail-call optimization since it avoids double calls. But what if neither version of the function makes double calls? Would the tail-recursive function still be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that question is hardware and language implementation dependent. In *most* cases, however, I'd have to think that a simple `GOTO` is faster than `CALL`-`RETURN` instruction pair.